# get back objectID after posting an image to mongoDb with multer

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, multer

I only would like to get back the objectID of the image stored in MongoDb after posting. My response does not contain that.
I would not like to write schemas or anything fancy, just get the objectID back.

```
app.post('/upload', upload.single('file'), (req, res) => {
    res.json();
});
```

This is where I post, and the response (res) does not contain the ObjectId.

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

gooot iiit

```
res.json({file: req.file});
```

this was the secret :)